# First-generation Kindle Fires ADB debugging

Tags: android, debugging, kindle-fire

I'm trying to use my Kindle for testing Android apps, but no avail. I follow the instructions [here](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/Connecting_your_Kindle_Fire_to_ADB.pdf) and [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/05-setting-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing) and [here](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/community/post/Tx3RZFBU0KJTSWS/Setting-up-the-ADB-Driver-for-Kindle-Fire-Devices), but still my Kindle is defined Windows 7 as a normal Kindle, not Android Composite ADB Interface.
Prompt me, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

There should be 2 hardware interfaces for your 1st Gen Kindle Fire, one for ADB, one for MSC (mass storage mode).

[image: 1st Gen Kindle Fire]

So it's normal for Windows to detect one of them as a normal Kindle. I would suggest you to check Device Manager and see if the 2nd interface showed up as an unknown device. Once you found it, you should be able to associate it with the Kindle Fire ADB driver with the following steps:

1. Right-click > `Update Drive Software`
2. `Browse my computer for driver software`
3. `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer`
4. `Show All Devices` > Next
5. `Have Disk`
6. `Browse` > select the location of your Kindle Fire driver
7. If everything goes well, you should be able to select `Android Composite ADB Interface`

Comment: But I do not have such a hardware interface. The problem is that Win7 automatically installs itself drivers when I connect the device and do not want to update them.

Comment: @astraport, you saw 2 "hardware" got added in Device Manager when you connect your Kindle Fire (regardless of what Windows recognized them as), right? I added some steps for setting up the ADB driver. Try associate one of the 2 "hardware" with the ADB driver and see if it works. Otherwise, can you post a screenshot of your Device Manager?

Comment: Thanks for your help. My computer has a Russian localization, I hope a screenshot will understandable. http://i.imgur.com/K10W1K5.png 
Yes, I did everything as instructed, but every time Windows not update the driver and display the message that employed drivers no need to update and Kindle is defined as MTP USB device.

Comment: Hmm...can you try right-click on "Kindle" and uninstall the driver, then re-connect the device and see if the 2nd hardware interface show up? In step #7 above, did you see the "Android Composite ADB Interface" option in the dialog?